# When to use ternary operators?

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator, conventions

Just being curious here, when is the desired moment (better readability?) for using `?:` ?

I mean, obviously this:

```
points = (someBool) ? 0 : 10
```

is better than this:

```
if someBool {
    points = 0
} else {
    points = 10
}
```

but then no one would want to read this:

```
someView.isHidden ? updateViewVisibility(desired: .Visible, forView: someView) : updateViewVisibility(desired: .Hidden, forView: someView)
```

So is there a guideline for all of this? Or is this just a *mood* thing?

Comment: Ha! Thanks, it is a duplicate. Just couldn't find anything when searching with Swift

Comment: `updateViewVisibility(desired: someView.isHidden ? .Visible : .Hidden, forView: someView)`

Comment: Nice!! Haven't crossed my mind that it could be written like this, thanks :)